# R For vs Apply, when to use each?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm just wondering when it is most appropriate to use for loops and when apply is better? I have done some reading on this topic.

Most of my loops are done using lapply as all that I've read says to do it that way rather than for. However today I wrote a for loop that for each name in a list, runs SQL (using RODBC) with the name in the list being in the WHERE clause and then saves the results to a folder.

Looks like this (not reproducible due to my sql connection):

```
for (i in df$V1){
    x <- sqlQuery(mycon, "select...")
    write.csv(x, paste0("sec/new/",i,".csv"), row.names = F)
}
```

I then thought it would be best to use lapply so wrote:

```
pblapply(df$V1, function(i) {
    x <- sqlQuery(mycon, "select...")
    write.csv(x, paste0("sec/new/new/",i,".csv"), row.names = F)
  })
```

The for loop took a couple hours max. Im using pblapply to track progress and surprisingly it says 5 hours. I know that my list starts with names that will give larger results such that pbapply will think it takes longer that in reality (I assume it guesses each i will take the same length of time).

I'm wondering though if there are best practices for certain tasks. I know the apply family has different version for lists, vectors, matrices etc. Are there situations where for loops are usually better than lapply and visa-versa?

I know that speed isn't always the priority, but I have no problem reading for loops in code ad wonder why they are looked down upon so much? Same for repeat and while, I'd usually just write a for loop that does the same thing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `for` loops are preferable if you don't need a return value but only a side effect like plotting or writing to a connection. Needing a `repeat` or `while` loop in R is very rare.

Comment: see Circle 4 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), "overvectorizing"

Comment: Thank you, most of my loops are creating subsets based specific criteria or applying functions to data and then writing the results.